# Parse.com Library internal exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone, parse-platform

I started develop my first C# app for WP8 with Visual Studio Express 2012 on Win8.1 and my HTC 8X WP8.0 device.
I create new app with Pivot template, add Parse.com library version 1.3.0 from NuGet.
Then I add some lines of code like in [Parse.com Quickstart Guide](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/windows_phone/existing)

```
using Parse;
```

and

```
public App()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

  ParseClient.Initialize("Here_My_App_Key", "Here_My_Client_Key");
}
```

I build it and launch on my device.
Immediately after calling `ParseClient.Initialize` app got unhandled exception from `Parse.Phone.DLL` and stopped work in `Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ....)`.

I try to catch and handle exceptions, but it looks like Library is not initialized.
I remove 1.3.0 version of library and install old spring version — it works very well.

I think, you can repeat this bug in three clicks.
Why does it cause? Is it internal Parse bug or some VS Project settings or WP version non-capability?

Comment: What is the exception being thrown? Double check and make sure that you're putting your app key and client key in correctly. If ParseClient needs to make an Http call to validate upon initialization, make sure that you have the Internet Client capability checked in your app manifest.

Comment: Keys are correct — old 1.2.x version works. I'm new on WP Platform, I will check the manifest, as you say. Thanks.